# NodeJs / React wan't refresh files over https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, npm

I have a boring problem that I can't solve..

I tried in all ways but I don't understand why if I call the application through the IP:3000 it loads updated files, but if I try to call it trough https://domainname.ext it doesn't want to serve new files.

I tried to delete node_modules and rebuild it (npm install); to run "npm run eject" and rebuild the app; pm2 kill and restart; reboot the server but nothing...

The App is configured to run with Nginx as reverse proxy over https.

Answer (score 0):

Classically one of the following solutions:

- Browser cache ("external" Domains are cached, IPs not). Try a different Browser
- Actually 2 apps running. Try to kill the process and see if it really goes down
- Nginx caching?

Comment: Yes, i tried this solutions - nothing heppened.

I disabled the nginx caching.

p.s. thanx for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Finally

in my server block of nginx configuration i just changed from localhost to IP addr

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://IP.ADDR:3000/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

}